# Quaternion correction

Tags: unity-game-engine, math

I'm trying to implement network correction for a client simulated Rigidbody. 30 times a seconds I get the target rotation from which I calculate the rotation correction. Then I apply this correction over a number of frames.

Network update:

```
rotationCorrection = receivedRotation * Quaternion.Inverse(transform.rotation);
```

Every frame:

```
var a = Mathf.Min(1, Time.deltaTime * 8);

var final = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, transform.rotation * rotationCorrection, a);
var actualCorrection = final * Quaternion.Inverse(transform.rotation);
rotationCorrection *= Quaternion.Inverse(actualCorrection);
//rotationCorrection = Quaternion.Slerp(rotationCorrection, Quaternion.identity, a); // First try

_rigidbody.MoveRotation(final);
```

The reason I don't just interpolate the current rotation to the corrected on is the GameObject contains a Rigidbody which should simulate the object in addition to the correction.

This does work sometimes (at least the first try version), except at angles between roughly -90 and 90. I suspect its the code to slerp the rotationCorrection to identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(work in progress since the question was not 100% clear)

The subtraction formulae yield wrong results. Please try using euler, subtract the angles and you can make the desired quaternion.

Are you sure you don't need Lerp instead of Slerp?

Anyway final should not use Lerp or Slerp.

If as `final` you want `transform.rotation * rotationCorrection` (which is the current rotation plus the correction), then just use it as that. Multiplications actually add the rotation.

Lerp and Slerp are to be used with an `a` parametric to time, where a==0 will return the starting rotation, a==1 will return the final rotation. So `a` should be scaled with time. If, on the other hand, the network correction is exactly what you need and you get it at specific fixed-time updates, then without any Lerp, might as well try `transform.rotation = transform.rotation*rotationCorrection`.

> ```
> rotationCorrection = receivedRotation * Quaternion.Inverse(transform.rotation);
> ```

What this does is return a rotation that starts from receivedRotation and ends to the opposite rotation of the current transform rotation. So neither the start nor the end point match with the current one.

so:

You set a final quaternion as currentRot * change

a starting as currentRot

and then update transform.rotation by making it = (S)Lerp with start, end and a parameter that equals 0 at starting time and 1 at ending time.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't want the client-side object to just snap to the correct position. Instead I want to apply parts of the correction over time. a is actually Time.deltaTime (I edited the post).

Comment: I updated my answer.... do not lerp final but do like I suggest and it will work :)

Comment: I updated the question. Just (S)lerping here won't sadly do, because the Rigidbody should still do its job. So the lerp target (transform.rotation * rotationCorrection) is not valid.

Comment: Ah got it then!

Comment: What about: first thing you let the rigidbody update by doing its job, then you add a fraction of the rotation (basing on the time or frames elapsed) and then you subtract this added amount to the correction rotation left. Until this correction rotation left is 0. Might that work?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do :) But it seems substracting the added correction from the correction rotation left does not coverge to zero. Somehow my math is off. The "first try" version does mostly work, but only if the GameObject faces a certain range of angles (-90,90).

Comment: Try lerp instead of slerp, first. The problem is anyway likely to be an inconsistent 'a'. If too much has elapsed, it will surpass the zero, if you get what I mean. I kind of dislike the Min with constants. You should just get one float for the start time of the whole rotation and then manage everything with current time. (current time is System.Time - rotationStartTime)

Comment: Lerp did not improve it. That's what I suspect too, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I just noticed an interesting thing. When I directly apply the correction the bug still appears. So the network update line seems already wrong:  rotationCorrection = receivedRotation * Quaternion.Inverse(transform.rotation);

Comment: Yes that one is definitely wrong. the inverse of the transform.rotation faces opposite and you rotate rotation Correction BY that rotation.

Comment: But I thought the receivedRotation minus the current rotation gives me the correction amount.

Comment: Ok no... :) What that expression does is very different. Can you avoid the need for subtraction at all and just have the "corrector" give you the desired correction? So that you already have it. Otherwise use euler and subtract the angles and ti will work. I will add it to my answer

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you for your time. I would have never guessed this part of the code was wrong. Should have checked by directly using rotationCorrection.

Comment: Well I am glad you fixed it :) Anytime. I love Unity.

Answer (score 0):

The network update was wrong. Corrected:

```
rotationCorrection = Quaternion.Inverse(transform.rotation) * receivedRotation;
```